# Issue in passing data through link in react function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Trying to pass data between two components through link in function component but not able to send data.

```
setFemaleListItems(
  categoryData
    .filter((data) => data.type === "female")
    .map((x) => (
      <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: "/Customizer",
            state: { val: "some data" },
          }}
        >
          <figure>
            <img src={x.thumbnail} alt="images" />
            <figcaption>
              <strong>{x.name}</strong>
              <span>From ${x.price}</span>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </Link>
      </div>
    ))
);
```

In the second component trying to fetch the data through this code:

```
import { useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Customizer = ({ route }) => {
  const { handle } = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  const { val } = location.state;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data from", val);
  });
};
```

**But getting this error**

[image: error]

**Please suggest any solution. Thanks**

Comment: first you have to navigate by clicking that `Link` only then the state is defined, it may be undefined to a second try using location object to access kyes, instead of destructuring

Comment: Is `Customizer` rendered within a routing context? Can you provide how `Customizer` is rendered, from itself all the way to any router you may have?

Comment: Do this `const { val } = location && location.state;` and let us know what happens (I'll explain later).

Comment: @MwamiTovi That will fail if `location` is undefined or null or not an object. Null checks are a good thing, but you still don't want to accidentally attempt to access properties of the falsey case. For what you suggest, you should provide a fallback to destructure from, i.e. `const { val } = location?.state || {}`.

Comment: @DrewReese you're right, the issue here though with what you've described above is that our friend doesn't seem to be using `.ts` but even still... our friend seems to want to use the variable `val` within the `useEffect`. So here's how my suggestion would help - initially you want `val` to defined only if `location.state` is defined otherwise `val` is undefined. And if you add the right checks, you can stop the `useEffect` from running, if you add `val` as a dependency. That's my thought process.